# Is the "in" keyword necessary when passing an argument to an "in" method parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, reference

This is how one would typically write code to call a method with an `in` parameter, i.e. without specifying the `in` keyword before the argument passed to the method.

Example:

```
static void Method1()
{
    var value = 1234;
    
    Method2(value);
}

static void Method2(in int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

However, I've realized that it's also possible to specify the `in` keyword before the argument passed to the method.

Example:

```
static void Method1()
{
    var value = 1234;
    
    Method2(in value);
}

static void Method2(in int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

**Question:**

Are both syntaxes equivalent or are there any subtle differences to be aware of?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier

Comment: `The in modifier is usually unnecessary at the call site. It is only required in the method declaration.`